# Using the heapq function 'nlargest' to find the peaks of an FFT and their corresponding frequencies in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, fft

I am using an FFT to look at the distortion I have on an output signal for an IC tester i am designing. I have two arrays, one containing the sampled frequencies, and the other containing the corresponding FFT values. I have been able to print the three highest FFT values using the nlargest function from the heapq library, but want to also print the corresponding frequency values from the x axis array. My partial code is below. the frequency values are stored in an array 'frq' and the FFT values in array 'Y'

```
Y = sci.fft(y)/n # fft computing and normalization
Y = Y[range(n/2)]
Y = abs(Y)
print heapq.nlargest(3, 20*np.log10(abs(Y)))
print heapq.nlargest(3, frq, key=lambda i: Y[i])
```

I receive the following error from the last line of code:

```
print heapq.nlargest(2, frq, key=lambda i: Y[i])
IndexError: index 500 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean something like:  `nlargest(3,enumerate(frq),key=lambda i,_:Y[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that will give 3 tuples corresponding to the highest

```
from itertools import izip
print heapq.nlargest(3, izip(frq, 20*np.log10(abs(Y))), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

You can also just put the Y first

```
print heapq.nlargest(3, izip(20*np.log10(abs(Y)), frq))
```

Comment: That works great, now I can just return one array with both the frequency and FFT info from my FFt function. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The *numpythonic* way of doing this would skip `heapq` altogether and go somethinkg like this:

```
idx = np.argsort(Y)[::-1][:3]
y_top_3 = 20*np.log10(Y[idx])
f_top_3 = frq[idx]
```

If you want to get an iterable of iterables, you could then do:

```
top_3 = np.vstack(f_top_3, y_top_3).T
```